# Selecting subsequent and preceding elements of a given element via CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I have a list:

```
<ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li class="selected">item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to select the 3rd and 4th items in this list via CSS? And more generally, all items that come after/before the `.selected` item?

Comment: [Give this a read](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048). What you are referring to is nth-child selectors.

Comment: You can do pretty much all of those, except for the previous sibling selection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select the succeeding elements, you would use the [general sibling combinator, `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

Despite not being able to select the previous sibling elements, you could solve this by styling all the elements to begin with, and then overwriting the styling by selecting the succeeding elements.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zsMr8/)

This will set the color of all the elements (except `.selected`) to red. It will then overwrite that styling and make the succeeding elements blue.

```
ul li:not(.selected) {
    color:red; 
}
ul .selected ~ li {
    color:blue;
}
```

Since `:not()` [isn't supported in IE8](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3), you could also use the following:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jQLYv/)

```
ul li {
    color:red; 
}
.selected {
    color:black;
}
ul .selected ~ li {
    color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a selector that matches elements preceded by another and this selector is a tilde `~`.

So, you can simply match all elements after `.selected` using:

```
.selected ~ LI
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vfNQ/) example.

For futher details, visit [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).